# 'else' statement not running in 'didSelectRowAt' function while executing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, if-statement

don't know whether it is common or not but in 'didSelectRowAt' function, 'if' statement is executing perfectly but 'else' statement is not and whenever i tap on the cell the checked property is always true down below is the code which might help :-

here is the code :-

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var vCData  = [Item]()

    let url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    var items = [Item]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCoinData(url: url)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        let arrayItem = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text        = arrayItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text  = arrayItem.symbol

        if arrayItem.checked == true{cell.accessoryType = .checkmark}
        else{cell.accessoryType = .none}

        return cell
    }
```

THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS :-

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        var selItem = items[indexPath.row]

        if selItem.checked == false {

            selItem.checked = true

            vCData.append(selItem)

        }else {                       // statement not working

            selItem.checked = false

            if let index : Int = self.vCData.index(where: {$0.name == selItem.name && $0.checked == selItem.checked && $0.buyPrice == selItem.buyPrice && $0.rank == selItem.rank && $0.symbol == selItem.symbol}) {

                self.vCData.remove(at: index)
                print(vCData,"\n")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func doneTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Set breakpoints in the else statement, and see if the app hits the breakpoint.

Comment: What is `Item`? Is it a class or struct? Based on your issue I would say it is a struct and you are experiencing the results of value types being copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Item` is a `struct` and not a `class`, your issue is the result of the fact that `struct` is a value type and copies are made when you assign from one variable to another.

In `didSelectRowAt` you update `selItem` but this does not change the copy stored in `items`.

The fix is simple. After your `if/else`, update `items` with the new `selItem`:

```
items[indexPath.row] = selfItem
```

On an unrelated note, I would replace the use of `reloadData` in `didSelectRowAt` with:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [ indexPath ], with: .fade)
```

No need to reload the whole table just to update one row.

Comment: Wouldn't replacing all instances of `selfItem` be better? No copying of the values is needed.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: If you do `items[indexPath.row] = selfItem`, then the values in `selfItem` will be copied again. This copy is unnecessary because you could just write `items[indexPath.row]`. No copying will occur. Well, I guess you could say this is micro-optimisation.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, doing `items[indexPath.row].checked = true` is another option.

Comment: another problem occurs now , i am unable to remove the element from vCData when its checked property is false. 'vCData.remove' not working in 'else' block

Comment: If you have a new issue you should post a new question with relevant details.